# Search for value and print something if found (BASH)

Tags: bash, grep

I have the following list:

```
    COX1
    COX1
    COX1
    COX1
    COX1
    Cu-oxidase
    Cu-oxidase_3
    Cu-oxidase_3
    Fer4_NifH
```

and I want to search if `COX1` and `Cu-oxidase` is in the list, I want to print `xyz`, if `Cu-oxidase_3` and `Fer4_NifH`is in the list too (independent if the first two are in the list, then it should print `abc`.

This is what I could script so far:

`if grep 'COX1' file.txt; then echo xyz; else exit 0; fi`

but it is of course incomplete.
Any solution to that?

ideally my output would be:

```
xyz
abc
```

Comment: I am not sure where you are stuck?  You know how to grep and you know how to use an 'if', what else would you like to know?  It only seems incomplete because you have not attempted to take it any further.

Comment: I am stuck at adding commands for either `COX1 & Cu-oxidase` or `Cu-oxidase_3 & Fer4_NifH` PLUS printing out different strings - where should I put it?

Comment: In bash you can use && to place an and in your test (or at least it will act like and if first command returns found).  I would also suggest using -q with grep so you do not get additional noise from the output of each grep.

Answer (score 0):

Awk lets you easily search for multiple regular expressions and print something else than the matched string itself. (`grep` can easily search for multiple patterns, too, but it will print the match or its line number or file name, not some arbitrary string.)

The following assumes that you have a single token per line. This assumption makes the script really simple, though it would also not be hard to support other scenarios.

```
awk '{ a[$1]++ }
    END { if (("COX1" in a) && ("Cu-oxidase" in a)) print "xyz";
        if (("Cu-oxidase_3" in a) && ("Fer4_NifH" in a)) print "abc" }' file.txt
```

This builds an associative array of each token (actually the first whitespace-separated token on each line) and then at the end, when it has read every line in the file, checks whether the sought tokens exist as keys in the array.

Performing a single pass over the input file is a big win especially if you have a large input file and many patterns. Just for completeness, the syntax for performing multiple passes with `grep` is very straightforward;

```
if grep -qx 'COX1' file.txt && grep -qx 'Cu-oxidase' file.txt
then
    echo xyz
fi
```

which can be further abbreviated to

```
grep -qx 'COX1' file.txt && grep -qx 'Cu-oxidase' file.txt && echo xyz
```

Notice the `-x` switch to require the whole line to match (otherwise the regex `'Cu-oxidase'` would also match on the *Cu-oxidase_3* lines).

Comment: well, talking about antipatterns… `awk` is an anti-pattern on its own 

Comment: Please explain? There are many things which the shell alone can't handle; learning to use the standard supporting tools is an important step in learning to write shell scripts.

Comment: First of all, I was just making humour (hence the smiley emoji) — that being said, my ***OPINION*** is that awk has its very own bizarre syntax, and usually when you start needing advanced awk, it's better to step up and use a proper dynamic language. *N.B.: I emphasize on the opinion part, I guess you'd disagree and I'd respect that. I'm not trying to start a flamewar ☺*

Answer (score -1):

Above is a very verbose way to achieve this. There are ways to write the same with less `if`s and less `grep`s, but I really wanted to show you the logic:

you run a grep command, check for its return value with `$?`, and finally acts on the conditions.

```
# default values
HAS_COX1=0
HAS_CUOX=0
HAS_CUO3=0
HAS_FER4=0

# run silently grep
grep -q 'COX1' file.txt
# check for return value and set variable accordingly
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then HAS_COX1=1; fi

# same as above
grep -q 'Cu-oxidase' file.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then HAS_CUOX=1; fi
grep -q 'Cu-oxidase_3' file.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then HAS_CUO3=1; fi
grep -q 'Fer4_NifH' file.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then HAS_FER4=1; fi

if [ $HAS_COX1 -eq 1 ]; then
  if [ $HAS_CUOX -eq 1 ]; then
    echo 'xyz'
    exit 0
  fi
fi

if [ $HAS_CUO3 -eq 1 ]; then
  if [ $HAS_FER4 -eq 1 ]; then
    echo 'abc'
    exit 0
  fi
fi

echo 'None of the checks where matched'
exit 1
```

Beware: *this code is untested, so there might be bugs ☺*

The code isn't perfect, as it cannot print both `'xyz'` and `'abc'` when both conditions are met (but that would be an easy fix with the syntax I provide). Also `$HAS_CUOX` will be set to `1` whenever `$HAS_CUO3` is found (no boundary checking in the `grep` regex).

You could take that code further by using a single grep for each set of conditions to check, using something like `'COX1\|Cu_oxidase'` as the regex for grep. And also fix the minor issues I mentioned above.

---

> ideally my output would be:
>   `xyz`
>   `abc`

You added your expected output after I wrote the above script, but given the elements I gave you, you should be able to figure how to improve that (basically removing the `exit 0` where I placed them, and doing `exit 1` when no output has been given.

Or just remove all `exit`s as a dirty solution.

Comment: This has syntax errors and several clunky (but as such harmless) antipatterns.

Comment: grep has `-q` option to avoid stdout as well as to be used as `if grep -q 'search' file`

Comment: for the note on context, I wrote that script on my phone with the SO app, so I had no access to a shell while writing it ☺.  And thank you, @sundeep, I always forget about `-q`, I'll fix that. @tripleee I don't really agree with your views on anti-pattern, my take on this version was to make it readable.